# Complex hashmap data structure for a dynamic multi option groupby in java - ideas to improve implementation for running groupbys on arbitrary data

Tags: java, spring, group-by, hashmap

I am writing a program that will run groupby on each feature column of ANY arbitrary file (no prior knowledge of data) against all numeric columns in the file. I want this process to be very fast but I want it to work first. I have 2 questions:

1). Is the below understanding correct as far as how this complex List of HashMaps data structure is represented visually (described in comments)?

```
    List<HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Number>>>> finalResult = 
            new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Number>>>>();
        /**
         * Result should contain something like this for population and other metrics:
         * [{population={state={Virginia=20000000, Texas=200000, NY=30000000}, 
         *      {Country={Africa=30000000, India=400000000}}, 
         *  {Temperature={state={Virginia=83, Texas=92, NY=72},
         *      {Country={Africa=90, India=88, England=65, Canada=69}}}},
         *  {LifeExpectancy={state={Virginia=77, Texas=83, NY=67},
         *      {Country={Africa=90, India=88, England=65, Canada=69}}}}]
         */
```

2). Is there a smarter way to store all this information? Any ideas in improving this data-structure design? Its basically going to store a list of aggregationtypes and the numeric metrics for each feature column.

Here is an example file (Which by the way could be any kind of file):

```
id;state;city;total_pop;avg_temp
1;Florida;;120000;76
2;Michigan;Detroit;330000;54
3;New Jersey;Newark;;34
4;Florida;Miami;200000;80
5;New Jersey;Jersey City;1200000;55
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be way easier to have a `Country` or `State` object that contains these attributes. Then you can sort using custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)s. You'd then end up with stuff like this:

```
Map<String, List<Country>> countryStatistics = new Map<>();    
countryStatistics.put(
    "population", 
    new ArrayList<Country>(
        Collections.sort(
            countries, 
            new Comparator<Country>() {
                int compare(Country c1, Country c2) {
                    return c1.getPopulation() - c2.getPopulation();
                }
            }
        )
    )
);
```

And so on, for each of the categories. You'd then have a map that maps each statistic to a sorted list of countries ordered by that statistic.

Based on your edit, for arbitrary data you could perhaps do something like this:

```
//there's probably a better name for this, but let's go with this for now
public class Data {
    private Map<String, Integer> attributes = new HashMap<>();

    public Integer getValue(String attribute) {
        return attributes.get(attribute); //This doesn't handle cases where
                                          //the attribute doesn't exist. Maybe
                                          //you want to return 0 for that. 
    }

    public Integer setValue(String attribute, Integer value) {
        attributes.put(attribute, value);
    } 
}
```

Then you would do something similar:

```
Map<String, List<Data>> dataStatistics = new Map<>();    
dataStatistics.put(
    "population", 
    new ArrayList<Country>(
        Collections.sort(
            countries, 
            new Comparator<Country>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Country c1, Country c2) {
                    return c1.getValue("population") - c2.getValue("population");
                }
            }
        )
    )
);
```

If you don't want to repeat code, you can create a factory method that returns an instance of `Comparator` that sorts based on the specified attribute:

```
public Comparator<Data> createComparatorForAttribute(final String attribute) {
    return new Comparator<Data>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Data d1, Data d2) {
            return d1.getValue(attribute) - d2.getValue(attribute);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: actually the file could be anything. Any kind of file can be ran through this groupby program.

Comment: So you want to sort arbitrary data by an arbitrary property?

Comment: Yep. I edited the question details. the file could literally be anything

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @TazMan, arbitrary vs non-arbitrary data handling is a big difference as I'm sure you know :)

Comment: Would abstracting part of the data structure into classes as you have done result in a performance increase? Or is it for simplicity purposes? If there is a performance increase, could you explain how that would be? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @TazMan It's mostly for simplicity and because it represents the data better. It's much easier to figure out what `Map<String, List<Data>>` means than `List<HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Number>>>>`.

Comment: Okay for some reason I find `List<HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Number>>>>` easier to comprehend because I dont have much object oriented experience. But what you are explaining is something I'm totally looking forward to try.

Comment: @TazMan Ah yes, it makes sense to you now because you're fully immersed in the context of the problem that you are solving. But try looking at it 6 months from now and you'll spend some time trying to figure out what that means because it's not immediately obvious :). I wish you good luck with your learning! :)